# DateCompare(date1, date2, "d") not behaving as expected ColdFusion 9?

Tags: date, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, date-comparison

I have started using DateCompare() function in one of my pages. I run into few problems.

First thing, the two date arguments that I use in my function sometimes can be empty. My argument Date 1 is coming from query and there is some situation when there is no records. In that case DateCompare function was throwing an error since can accept only date values.

Second problem is when I tried to check if my `Date1` is greater than `Date2`, using "d" for days difference. I used 1 that should indicate that `Date1` is greater, but my logic still processed when `Date1` is less than or equal to `Date2`.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to compare dates in ColdFusion and if there is better way to approach this problem? Here is my example:

```
<!--- This arguments user picks on the screen with date picker --->
<!--- Example startDt value passed to server side: 03/23/2017 --->
<cfargument name="startDt" type="string" required="yes">
<!--- This argument is coming from the query and sometimes can be blank --->
<!--- Example curBegDt value passed to server side: 03/30/2017 ---> 
<cfargument name="currentBeginDt" type="string" required="no" default=""> 

<cfif DateCompare(trim(arguments.currentBeginDt),trim(arguments.startDt),"d") EQ 1>
  Do INSERT/UPDATE SQL Query
</cfif>
```

As you can see from the code above my INSERT/UPDATE should execute only if currentBeginDt is greater than startDt but also in the case when currentBeginDt is blank/empty. If anyone have suggestion how to solve this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to understand about that function is it's called **Date**Compare, not StringCompare ;-) It is designed to compare date objects, not strings or empty strings.

Yes, CF lets you be lazy and pass in date *strings*. However, CF still needs to convert those strings into date objects before it can compare them. So you are leaving the interpretation of those string entirely up to CF. Depending on the input, it may work .. or you may get some unexpected/wrong/confusing results.

The best way to ensure *consistent* results is to:

1. Validate the input to ensure it actually IS a valid date. If not, abort or apply appropriate error handling.
2. Otherwise, convert the input string into a date object using functions like [ParseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html) or [LSParseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsedatetime.html), both of which support a "format" argument for parsing as of CF10. For CF9 and earlier, you will need to roll-your-own.
3. After you are sure you have valid date objects, pass them into [DateCompare()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateCompare.html)

> my logic still proccessed when date 1 is equal or less than date

Most likely because you are using strings, and CF is interpreting those strings differently than you are expecting. We would need to see an example of the actual values to provide more specifics.

Comment: What if I pass the dates from JavaScript, both of them are created with new Date()? Would that work in DateCompare or I still have to create date objects in ColdFusion?

Comment: (Edit) Source does not matter unless you can guarantee the input - which you can't with client side data. With unknown input, always validate. Technically date objects are not *required* if the input is ALWAYS in a specific (standard U.S.) format. However, since that is usually not the case, using date objects is preferable. That is the only way to guarantee you get the expected results.

Comment: What are the actual values of the two date strings?

Comment: I have updated my question with examples for both date values.

Comment: (Edit) Thanks, but those values do not produce the results you described: http://trycf.com/gist/7063788512b1df9e35eefe1b2fe462f5/acf?theme=monokai . Are you sure they are in the correct order? That cfif checks that currentBeginDt is greater than startDt.

Comment: Sorry it's other way around, in that case my DateCompare should catch that.

Comment: (Edit) Check the `len()` first and skip the date comparison if it is empty. `<cfif !len(arguments.currentBeginDt) || dateCompare(...) eq 1>`. Though again, no guarantees dateCompare won't crash or return the wrong values if the two arguments are not valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
<cfif NOT isDate(arguments.currentBeginDt) 
   OR DateCompare(trim(arguments.currentBeginDt),trim(arguments.startDt),"d") EQ 1>
```

...will do the insert/update query if date1 is after date2 OR date1 is not a date.

If date1 and date2 are truly equal, then the result of DateCompare should be 0.  If you're getting 1 and think it's wrong, then check the dates, because they're probably not what you think they are.

Comment: While great in theory, you should not rely on IsDate. It is notoriously "generous" about what it considers a "date", and returns true in many cases you would not expect. For example, `IsDate("1.5")` returns true. It also uses similar rules to DateCompare when converting strings into dates (US date rules). So aside from ignoring empty strings, most likely the end result will be the same.

Comment: It won't return true for an empty string, though, which is what he wanted to catch.

Comment: (Edit) A trim and len check is better for that use case. Unless the strings are *always* in a standard US date format that CF can parse, you still need additional validation. Otherwise, there is no guarantee they will be converted correctly by DateCompare(). Most, if not all, of the standard date functions [always use US date formatting rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557244/coldfusion-10-dateformat-issue/16569306#16569306) when implicitly converting from string to date.

Comment: *which is what he wanted to catch* On second read, yes it would handle that case, so I retracted the down vote. However, it is still unwise to rely on implicit conversion of arbitrary date strings. It will always bite you in the end.